# id sci-fi short story, lovers time travel together in a city apartment

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I remember in high school late 90s reading a short story probably in an anthology or collection about two lovers (man and woman), who time travel while they’re together in their apartment bedroom (possibly New York or a large undefined city).

The way I remember how they time travel is when they are in the bedroom together time outside goes quicker than inside (a few hours might be a day).

I remember as the story went on they stayed in their bedroom more often and only went out for shopping groceries so were spending less and less time in real world time.

They lost their jobs and might have invested in stocks or something to make money I can’t remember that part exactly.

It was probably written by an American author in an American short story collection. It was a simple well executed and romantic story about how time seems to go so fast when you’re together with a loved one. . It also had a great ending where they ceased to exist or something. As the landlord visited and the apartment was empty or something. That climactic ending gave you a nice chill wow feeling. 
I’d like to find it again because it is one of the stories I always remember but don’t know what it’s called.

Comment: To when do they travel?

Comment: They travel forward in time only. So as in when they are together in the apartment bedroom time doesn’t exist or is slowed down.

Comment: Already asked (sigh): [Story about two lovers who can stop time when they're touching - maybe in Omni](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174775/story-about-two-lovers-who-can-stop-time-when-theyre-touching-maybe-in-omni)

Comment: @Spencer, voting to reopen, as this was closed as duplicate against a question without an accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is "[Rent Control](http://www.williamflew.com/omni13d.html)" by Walter Tevis. [It appeared](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?59898) in the October 1979 issue of *Omni* magazine.

> They never understood it, and they told nobody. It was relativity, they decided. They had found, indeed, a perfect place together, where subjective time raced and the external world stood entirely still.
>
> It did not work anywhere but in their loft bed -- and only when they touched. They could stay there for hours or days, although there was no way they could tell how long the "time" had really been; they could make love, sleep, read, talk, and no time passed whatever.

Only one detail doesn't match perfectly:

> But when the landlord came in, through the empty shelves in what was for him the next day, he found them in the loft bed, back to back, each staring into a different mirror. They were perfectly beautiful, with healthy, clear complexions, youthful figures, dark and glistening hair. But they had no minds at all. They were not even like beautiful children, there was nothing there but prettiness.

Comment: Awesome thanks Spencer! Ah i don’t remember the ending that way I must have remembered it incorrectly. I’m pretty sure this is it. Thanks.